# how to position the default activity indicator for webview in appcelerator to centre?

Tags: webview, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, activity-indicator

I have created a webview using the following:

```
var webview= Ti.UI.createWebView({
    height :"800",
    width:"600" });
```

When I open any document in webview the default activity indicator is seen in top left corner. How can I position it to centre of the webview?

System Requirements:
Application type: Mobile Titanium SDK: 4.0.GA Platform & version: iOS 8 xcode 6 Device: iPad Host OS: iOS

Answer (score 1):

I found your question on appcelerator here: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/31281/default-activity-indicator-for-webview-shows-on-left-of-screen-and-is-cut-off

They suggest you either set the width and height to 100% or you add the webview to a view